# How to generate cryptographic key in the form of a binary string 16 bytes long in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to store a string in encrypted form in mysql DB, so looking for two way encryption, I found a guide about [openssl_encrypt / openssl_decrypt](http://thefsb.tumblr.com/post/110749271235/using-opensslendecrypt-in-php-instead-of)

```
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext,  'AES-128-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$plaintext  = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'AES-128-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

That guide doesn't explain how to generate cryptographic key in the form of a binary string 16 bytes long for `$key` and crypto-secure random binary string 16 bytes long for `$iv`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I use `mcrypt_encrypt` using it like this `mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB))` The salt needs to be saved somewhere as it is needed to decrypt the data. `$salt` contains the salt you wanna use, so you can pass your own salt.

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);` and `$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);`

Should generate you a random 16 byte / 128-bit key and iv.

Comment: okay, I tried that, It is generating some non standard text (for english i.e.) Is it possible to make it generate standard english characters?

Comment: The key and IV are meant to be random, not english readable characters ;). You could enter standard english characters or `MD5` hash a value and use that output as the key and IV, but it's not suggested.

Comment: @Matt $key has value different every-time, how to save or store it?